# Jmockit mocking issue

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I am new to Junit and Jmockit. I wrote an example and want to test that using mocking, but I was stuck with an error.

```
public class First {

    public static int square(int number) {

        int result = number * number;
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Second {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number = 5;

        number = new Second().xi(number, number);
        System.out.println(number);
    }

    public int xi(int number, int number1) {
        number = First.square(number) + First.square(number1);
        return number;

    }

}
```

---

```
public class SecondTest {

    Second second = new Second();

    @Test
    public void testXi() {
        new Expectations() {

            {

                First.square(5);
                result = 25;
            }

        };
        int mk = second.xi(5, 5);
        assertEquals(50, mk);
    }
}
```

When I tried to run this SecondTest.java then i got the following error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at
>   this point; please make sure such invocations appear only after the
>   declaration of a suitable mock field or parameter     at
>   SecondTest$1.(SecondTest.java:17)   at
>   SecondTest.testXi(SecondTest.java:12)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

I couldn't find any error in the code.

Comment: Where did you search, exactly? The JMockit documentation (Getting Started page, Tutorial, API docs) clearly say that types need to be mocked by using one of the mocking annotations before you can record expectations. Also, that is what the error message is saying: "...make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable mock field or parameter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare something like `@Mocked First firstInstance` in the test class (class level, not method level).

Then you need to make the expectation `firstInstance.square(5); result = 25`

This in essence tells jmockit that you want the First class to be mocked out, and that it should exchange all instances of the First class with the instance firstInstance. Then you tell it that you are expecting a call to this instance for the method xi(int, int) with the values 5, 5, and you want it to return 25 back.

Comment: but square is a static method .

Comment: square is a static method, yes. But xi(int, int) is not.

Comment: However i got this error , when i tried it.
mockit.internal.UnexpectedInvocation: Unexpected invocation of:
First#square(int number)
   with arguments: 5
 at First.square(First.java)
 at Second.xi(Second.java:11)

Comment: Ah, since you are calling the first.square twice, and expectations are really strict about that. could either define the expecation twice, set `firstInstance.square(5); times = 2; result = 25;` or switch to NonStrictExpecations

Comment: times=2 helped . I thought writing expectation once is fine. But is it really necessary to mention "times"???

Comment: For Expectations you need to very very specifically specify exactly the chain of events you are expecting and in exactly which order. Which is why I tend to, in most cases, write NonStrictExpectations. Expectations implicitly assumes times = 1 and in-order, NonStrictExpectations assume any times, any order.

Comment: 1) The mocking declaration can be either a mock field or a mock parameter (at the test level); 2) the expectation should be `First.square(5)` as the method is `static`; 3) JMockit does *not* "exchange instances", it mocks the class therefore mocking all instances, while allowing the instance created for the mock field/parameter to be used as a "representative" for all instances (and of course in the case of `static` methods there are *no* instances involved).